# How can I loop through nested json and get array unique value from field

Tags: angularjs

I got this format in json.
I need unique values of "volume". So in result I'd get only '30' and '40'.
I used loop inside of another loop, but it returns unique values from each product, which is not what I want.
I'm using Angular 1 in Ionic.

```
{

"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Category title",
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "product title",
                "volume": "40"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "product title",
                "volume": "30"
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Another Category title",
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "product title",
                "volume": "40"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "product title",
                "volume": "30"
            }
        ]
    }

]

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this it will work :**

**JSON :**

```
var obj = {
    "data": [{
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Category title",
            "products": [{
                "id": 1,
                "title": "product title",
                "volume": "40"
            }, {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "product title",
                "volume": "30"
            }]
        },

        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Another Category title",
            "products": [{
                "id": 3,
                "title": "product title",
                "volume": "40"
            }, {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "product title",
                "volume": "30"
            }]
        }

    ]

};
```

**Logic implementation :**

```
var arr = [];
for (var item in obj.data) {
  for (var innData in obj.data[item].products) {
   var volume =  obj.data[item].products[innData].volume;
   if(arr.indexOf(volume) == '-1') {
     arr.push(volume);
   }
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

**Output :**

[image]

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bo2drv5x/

Answer (score 0):

To get the unique values

```
var uniqueVolumes = $.unique($.map(json.data, function(datum) { 
        return datum.products.map(function(product) { 
                                  return product.volume;
         });
    });
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using core java script you can find like this:

```js
var jsonData = {"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Category title",
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "product title",
                "volume": "40"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "product title",
                "volume": "30"
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Another Category title",
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "product title",
                "volume": "40"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "product title",
                "volume": "30"
            }
        ]
    }

]

};
var uniqueArr = [];
var jsonData = jsonData["data"];
var fullObjectLength = Object.keys(jsonData).length
for(var i=0; i<fullObjectLength;i++)
{
 //console.log(jsonData[i]["products"]);
  var jsonProductsLength = jsonData[i]["products"].length;
  for(var j=0; j<jsonProductsLength; j++)
  {
    var volumeKeyValue = jsonData[i]["products"][j]["volume"];   
    var itemTobePushedInArray = uniqueArr.indexOf(volumeKeyValue) == -1;
    if(itemTobePushedInArray)
    {
     uniqueArr.push(volumeKeyValue);
     console.log(uniqueArr);
    }
  }
}
```